# Finding the total number of papers published in a given journal, for a given year

Tags: publications, journals, web-of-science

Is there any way that one can find the percentage of papers from a certain journal that meet a given keyword?

The numerator of that fraction (the number of papers that conform to the keyword who were published in a given journal) can be found easily enough with a simple search. But the hardest part really comes down to finding the denominator of the fraction, that is, the **total number of papers** that were published in a given year, across multiple journals (thus, using the same metrics for all to enable comparison).

Services from Web of Science/Knowledge (InCites JCR etc) don't seem to help here. The only resource I found that gives this total number is https://scirev.org/, but many important multidisciplinary journals or general-psychology journals are not listed there.

Comment: Have you tried asking them...

Comment: No, as that would probably constitute a pre-submission enquiry, which are not allowed in the journals I have in mind

Comment: Why would asking how many be a pre-submission? What are you hiding?

Comment: What makes you think I'm hiding something. Point is, the total number of articles published in any one year is available for some journals (on their website, or on SciRev), but not for others, making such comparisons difficult.

Comment: The way you answered my comment... still you could ask.

Comment: Can't you just search by publication name and publication year? Basically the same search, but without requiring the keyword?

Comment: You mean as a way to find the total number of papers published that year in that journal? I think the rounding error would be so great in a e.g. Google SCholar search, that that total number would be very unreliable. Cf also the controversy relating "total number of citable items" (denominator of the JIF fraction)

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to be "number of articles per year in given journal" or something, since that is what you're really looking for. Is it possible for you to tell us what journal this is? And my understanding is that a "pre-submission inquiry" is a question relating to your submission (such as, "would this topic be suitable for your journal?") The rule should not categorically forbid all contact with the editorial staff as long as you one day plan to submit a paper to the journal...

Comment: Good point, will edit as you suggest

Comment: OP, is the journal indexed in WoS?

Comment: I actually intend to compare across several journals, and haven't checked whether all are indexed in WoS - I'd guess most are.

Answer (score 1):

If the journal is indexed in Web of Science, this can be easily searched for. You mention it doesn't seem to help, but I don't understand why. In the main search window, search for 1) publication name = [name of journal] and 2) published in whichever year you're interested in.

Comment: I just don't know if the total numbers you get from a search like this truly reflects the number of papers published. For instance, WoS returns 25,334 hits for a search with journal name=Scientific Reports, and year=2017. A more trustworthy/realistic number would be obtained from the journal itself, but then one runs into the problem that not all journals report this.

Comment: There's a way to do the search in WoS to get the journal with that exact title.